# Need assistance with C program function

Tags: c

Just to start the things off, this is a school project.

Basically the program does create a new dataset 'enimet' where it loads a set of data, and does it again with name 'snimet' and loads a new portion of data.

The following codes are in the main program:

```
printf("Give the dataset a name: ");
scanf("%s", uusinimi);
pAlkuTulos = analysoiData(pAlku, pAlkuTulos, uusinimi);
TulostaVikaTulos(pAlkuTulos);
```

Then I ask to print all data

```
TulostaTulos(pAlkuTulos);
```

This is the part where I'm having issues (printing out)

```
void TulostaVikaTulos(SolmuTulos *pAlkuTulos) {
    printf("Datasetti Nimiä PitMin PitMax PitKA\n");
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%s  %7.0f%7.0f%7.0f%6.1f\n", ptr->nimi, ptr->nimia, ptr-> pitmin, ptr->pitmax, ptr->pitKA);
        ptr = ptr->NextTulos; } }
```

A peak inside .h file:

```
struct NodeTulos {
    char *nimi;
    float nimia, pitmin, pitmax, pitKA;
    struct NodeTulos *NextTulos;
};
typedef struct NodeTulos SolmuTulos;
void TulostaTulos(SolmuTulos *pAlkuTulos);
```

So I basically 1. Create dataset named 'enimet' -> load data to it, 2. Create new dataset named 'snimet' -> load data to it -> print everything out.
It should print:

```
enimet 500 3 11 5.1  
snimet 500 2 17 7.8
```

But it does print:

```
snimet 500 3 11 5.1  
snimet 500 2 17 7.8
```

So it doesn't carry the 'enimet' over.

AnalysoiData in .h

```
SolmuTulos *analysoiData(Solmu *pAlku, SolmuTulos *pAlkuTulos, char *nimi);
```

.c

```
SolmuTulos *analysoiData(Solmu *pAlku, SolmuTulos *pAlkuTulos, char *nimi) {
    float i=0;
    float kaikki=0;
    int lyhin=100, pisin=0;
    float ka;

    Solmu *ptr = pAlku;
    SolmuTulos *ptrTulos, *ptrNew;

    while (ptr != NULL) {
        kaikki = kaikki + strlen(ptr->nimi);
        i++;
        if (strlen(ptr->nimi) < lyhin) {
            lyhin = strlen(ptr->nimi);
        }
        else if (strlen(ptr->nimi) > pisin) {
            pisin = strlen(ptr->nimi);
        }

        ptr = ptr->Next;
    }

    ka = kaikki/i;
    ptrNew = (SolmuTulos*)malloc(sizeof(SolmuTulos));
    if (ptrNew == NULL) {
        perror("Muistin varaus epäonnistui");
        exit(1);
    }

    strcpy(ptrNew->nimi, nimi);
    ptrNew->nimia = i;
    ptrNew->pitmin = lyhin;
    ptrNew->pitmax = pisin;
    ptrNew->pitKA = ka;
    ptrNew->NextTulos = NULL;
    if (pAlkuTulos == NULL) {
        pAlkuTulos = ptrNew;
    }
    else {
        ptrTulos = pAlkuTulos;
        while (ptrTulos->NextTulos != NULL) {
            ptrTulos = ptrTulos->NextTulos;
        }
        ptrTulos->NextTulos = ptrNew;
    }

    return pAlkuTulos;
}
```

Comment: You need to show the actual source in your question that is where you think the problem is. Not post your entire source package as a zip file link. It's good that you have put some effort into this, but what have you done for debugging to narrow down the problem besides just editing your code?

Comment: The program consists of 4 files, and I'm not 100% sure where the problem actually is. The code is also pretty long, so I thought it's better to upload them as a file.   
I don't understand why it's printing it out wrong, as with all sense it should work fine. I have tried troubleshooting, but I haven't got any results. It either prints it out wrong, or I get errors.

Comment: See [How to Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't go somewhere else to download your code. The relevant code In the form of that [mcve] must be here, in the question itself, where it is available for future reference.

Comment: I've provoided the code of two files where it all should happen.

Comment: Remove as much code as you possibly can while preserving the problem. Replace user input with hard code. Keep going until you have a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Likely you will find the bug yourself in the process.

Comment: This thread become a bit messy. Should I keep editing this or start a new one?

Comment: @Armeija Please continue editing it; the edit history will itself act as part of the post and you can always clean up the post contents. The comments are bound to get messy, but that is very common for questions that undergo discussion and revision.

Comment: Edited the question. Should be much clear now.

Comment: Please show the definition of `analysoiData`.  I'm guessing your problem is not with printing but with storing.

Comment: Edited it to the OP

Comment: What is the type of `uusinimi`, and (if it's a pointer) did you allocate memory for it?  I can see in your `analysoiData` there is already undefined behavior because you are calling `strcpy` writing to memory referenced by an uninitialized pointer.  `strcpy` does not allocate memory.  And your earlier `malloc` call only allocated memory for the structure itself, not the string that you want to store in it.

Comment: uusinimi is just a char

Comment: That is impossible.  It cannot be a `char` only, or you would not be able to compile your program.  Do you mean it's a `char*`?  Or is it a `char` array? Show the code that defines this variable, and the code that allocates memory for it.

Comment: char nimi[20], uusinimi[20];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior, where you attempt to copy a string into memory referenced by a pointer that was never initialized.  It happens here:

```
ptrNew = (SolmuTulos*)malloc(sizeof(SolmuTulos));
if (ptrNew == NULL) {
    perror("Muistin varaus epäonnistui");
    exit(1);
}

strcpy(ptrNew->nimi, nimi);
```

Since the `nimi` member is of type `char*`, you must allocate sufficient memory to receive the string `nimi`.  This can be achieved as follows:

```
ptrNew->nimi = malloc(strlen(nimi) + 1);
if (ptrNew->nimi)
    strcpy(ptrNew->nimi, nimi);
```

Alternatively, you could define the `nimi` member in your struct as `char nimi[20]`.  I suggest this in response to your comment that states you defined `uusinimi` as a 20-byte `char` array.  So, you could change the definition of `struct NodeTulos` to:

```
struct NodeTulos {
    char nimi[20];
    float nimia, pitmin, pitmax, pitKA;
    struct NodeTulos *NextTulos;
};
```

Which approach you take will depend entirely on your program's requirements.